# How to get ThreadPoolExecutor style concurrency with custom threads and objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

So I have a series of remote http listeners (nodes) that I have represented in code with Python objects. I have a queue of commands that I need to execute in parallel in no particular order. Each node can only execute one command at a time.

So basically I'm looking for some way to represent these objects as a pool of threads that have a queue of tasks to complete. As one node completes it's task it goes back into the pool and gets another task from the queue, until all the tasks are complete.

For example, a node object and it's list might look like this.

```
class Mork():
    def __init__(self, name) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.introduction = f"Hi I'm {self.name}"
    
    def speak(self):
        print(f"{self.introduction}.")
        sleep(1)
    
    def scream(self):
        print(f"{self.introduction.upper()}!")
        sleep(2)
    
    def whisper(self):
        print(f"{self.introduction.lower()}...")
        sleep(3)
```

And the executing thread might look like this.

```
class Processor(object):
  """Process the data."""

  def __init__(self, node):
    self.node = node

  def __call__(self, mode):
    """Do something"""
    if mode == "speak":
        self.node.speak()
    elif mode == "scream":
        self.node.scream()
    elif mode == "whisper":
        self.node.whisper()
    else:
        print(f"{self.node.name} doesn't know how to {mode}...")
```

Now I need something that will use these classes like so

```
nodes = [Mork("Thad"), Mork("Chad"), Mork("Brad")]
tasks = ["speak", "scream", "whisper", "speak", "speak", "whisper", "scream", "scream", "scream"]
thread_pool = []

for node in nodes:
   thread_pool.append(Processor(node))

# complete_all_tasks_using_threads(thread_pool, tasks)
```

It's the last bit that is giving me trouble. How, with the tools python provides, do I make sure the threads execute without collision, i.e: a node being asked to complete 2 tasks at once.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Have you looked at `ThreadPoolExecutor` in the `concurrent.futures` module?

Comment: @daniel Thanks! I have. My interim solution involves a queue holding my nodes that is passed to a function holding the code from the Processor `__call__` method. I map that function to my list of tasks and let 'er rip. It works ok but it smells like a hack. Basically I am using my node queue as a semaphore for the ThreadPoolExecutor. I am sure there is a better pattern somewhere I am missing. It seems like such a common problem..